# No color scheme in tmux 2.1

Tags: vim, ubuntu-16.04, tmux, rxvt, urxvt

if I `echo $TERM` from my terminal, I get `rxvt-unicode-256color` and `tput colors` shows `256`.  I like the custom color scheme that I have there as defined in my .Xresources file.  However, when I launch `tmux -2`, things change.  `echo $TERM` shows `tmux-256color` while `tput colors` still shows `256`, but all text is single color unless I am in vim...and that is even more strange because the color scheme in vim (inside tmux) is different than the color scheme of vim in my regular terminal (rxvt).

Only line that I currently have in ~/.tmux.conf is `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"`

Can someone please help me line these two up to match?

Comment: I am on version 2.1 via default Ubuntu 16.04 repos

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

rather than

```
set -g default-termainal "tmux-256color"
```

Comment: you are correct...must have typed too fast as "terminal" is indeed what I have in my .conf file.  I just updated the original post; thanks for pointing that out.